# How to know if an item was selected in a specific lisbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

How can I know if an item was selected in a specific listbox?

For example, if my listboxes are `listBox1` and `listBox2`,
and I want to know if the user selected an item on `listBox1`.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the same [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler to your Listboxes. Then use `sender` parameter to determine which listbox is triggered the event.

```
listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;

private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    if(sender != null) MessageBox.Show(listBox.Name);
}
```

Comment: There is no .Name option.

Comment: @user2992413 sorry it should be listBox.Name

Answer (score 0):

If you're using visual studio, double-click the listbox and visual studio will create a method for you that subscribes to the SelectedIndexChanged event. Inside this method, you can define what code to execute when an item for that listbox is selected.